# WidgetKit Image from URL

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I'm trying to load an image from URL to a Widget. I've done so before just fine in another project I've recently made. Now I'm trying to do the same exact method and seeing some strange errors `Argument type 'URL' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'` and `Cannot convert value of type 'ExampleWidgetExtension.Data' to expected argument type 'Foundation.Data'`. My other project works just fine and I'm using `Codable` data just like before. Everything but the image seems to be working.

```swift
struct ExampleWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
            ForEach(entry.model?.example.results?.prefix(1) ?? [], id: \.id) { example in
                /*
                 Text(example.data.title ?? "")
                 .fontWeight(.bold)
                 .font(Font.system(.caption))
                 .lineLimit(1)
                 */
                if let url = URL(string:example.data.url ?? ""),
                   let imageData = try? Data(from: url),
                   let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.all, 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no initializer on `Data` (the one in Foundation) that takes a `URL` in the `from:` field. The reason that you're getting an error is that `Data(from:)` expects a `Decoder` in that argument. You say that you have another project where you do that, but you must have some sort of custom extension on `Data` for that to work.

What you want is `let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)`

---

As pawello points out in the comments, in looks like you may have a custom type in your project named `Data` already, so it may be necessary to do the following:

```
try? Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url)
```

You may want to consider renaming *your* `Data` type to something else to avoid namespace collisions with Foundation's `Data`

Comment: Also the OP probably has a custom Data struct as in the error message we see `'ExampleWidgetExtension.Data'`. It might be needed `try? Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: Oh -- good catch. The dangers of Swift namespaces...

Comment: I'm still getting `Argument type 'URL' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'` after changing to `let imageData = try? Foundation.Data(from: url),`

Comment: @cole It's `Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url)`, not `Foundation.Data(from: url)`.

Comment: @pawello2222 the image's are working but the other data is now not showing when it was previously. Not sure what causing this now. I'm seeing more errors messages in console. `nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:` and `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002`.

Comment: What "other data"? You don't reference anything else in the code you've shown except for what is commented out

Comment: It was the commented out data. I was only testing the images because they weren’t working. The title data was working fine if I remove the image. There’s more data just made a mock-up for easy reading.

Comment: So you've uncommented it and you're saying that now that you're getting the image, the `Text` isn't showing? Is the image just taking up the available space and it's pushing the `Text` out of the widget's frame?

Comment: No, the image frame is fine. The large widget contains the images, the smaller widget contains text. Nothing is showing for the large or small widget text. Even though there’s no images in the smaller widget.

Comment: Are you positive there's data in `entry.model?.example.results?`? Lots of optionals going on there... If you try to put in dummy text, does that show?

Comment: @jnpdx foregroundColor(Color.white) might do it.. it's been a long day.‍♂️ It's working just fine https://imgur.com/a/XZRG2i3